# Google Places Autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am setting up a google places autocomplete on my script and getting this error "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API" when i am typing a place

```
        var input = document.getElementById('np_autocomplete');             
        autocomplete  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };
              var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
              });
              autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }               
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.fillInAddres);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(event) { 
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's a problem we can't solve - you've made too many requests today.

Comment: You've already answered your question. Your daily request quota has been exceeded. Figure out how to make less requests on your current API key, or use another one.

Comment: After a couple of seconds when i try again, it works. Then after typing again, it returns the same error. Doesnt happen when i copy paste though.